# How to relate a differential form in the algebraic setting to the "differential" setting

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying an example : { (x,y) / $x^{4} =  y^{2}$ } . 
I want to compute differential forms at (1,1) (for example).

It is an algebraic variety. It is a differential manifold...except that (0,0) is singular,so I may work on an open subset : a neighbourhood of (1,1), not containing (0,0), U.
I want to see what algebraic one forms and differential forms look like, in one case using the definition  , in the second, as df, where f $\in $ C $^{\infty}$(U).

I compute : an element of the maximal ideal containing (1,1), is a real polinomyal on   ($x^ {2} - y)  . $ So an (algebraic) form is of the form p = a ($x^ {2} - y)$ + b. 
In the differential manifold case, using the fact that the dimension is one , one has that a differential form is determined by a  C $^{\infty}$ function on U. That is the same as a function on an open interval. 
Where does th second construction "see" the polynomial equation? An interval and a neighbourhood in the parabole are diffeomorphic. So algebraic information is lost?

May be it is a far fetched example, but I wanted to get a reducible polynomial, and see easily what the maximal ideal looked like.

Comment: Were you thinking of the $I / I^2$ formulation?  If so, that's where $I$ is the ideal of the diagonal in the variety product: the product is essentially $\{ (x, y, x', y') \mid x^4 = y^2, (x')^4 = (y')^2 \}$ with ring of functions $k[x,y,x',y'] / \langle x^4 - y^2, (x')^4 - (y')^2 \rangle$ and the diagonal corresponds to the ideal generated by $x-x', y-y'$.

Comment: I see...thanks.Anyway, a silly question : $x^ {4} =y^ {2} $? (in the last sentence...)